# Update column of the cached table - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I've cached the event table in controller using output cache

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 30000, Location = 
System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
public ActionResult Campings(int id)
{
   Pages page = db.Pages.FirstOrDefault(p =>p.Id == id);
   page.VisitCount = page.VisitCount + 1;
   db.Entry(page).State = EntityState.Modified;
   db.SaveChanges();

   MemoryCache.Default["cachedPage"] = page;

   return View(page);
}
```

And I've implemented page visit count increment code every time the page got hit. Cache is working fine but since the table is cached, page visit count won't increase when the page is visited after first time till the cache got cleared.

Is there a method to update cached table or is there a better way to cache the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for the action that you do not want to be cached.

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
```

---

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
public ActionResult YourActionWithoutCaching()
{
  //-------------------------------
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the increment code is inside action result. Please find the edited question